# KVC is not working

Tags: ios, kvc

I am trying very simple KVC on iOS to learn.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface KVC : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *string;
@end
```

In .m file

```
@implementation KVC
@synthesize string=_string;
@end
```

in main

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    KVC *kvc;
    [kvc setValue:@"tunvir" forKey:@"name"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[kvc valueForKey:@"name"]);
}
```

I am expecting "**tunvir**" in console but it return null!
Thanks

Comment: Side note - you don't need the `@synthesize` line with newer versions of the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to allocate and initialize the object.
And you defined the property with a name `string` so you should use that name not the `name`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    KVC *kvc;
    kvc = [[KVC alloc] init];
    [kvc setValue:@"tunvir" forKey:@"string"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[kvc valueForKey:@"string"]);
}
```

Comment: I an not clear how it helps coder to write dynamic code.would you give any link that van help me.Thanks

Comment: @TunvirRahmanTusher Don't forget to accept the answer that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing initialization of an instance for the object in the stack.

```
   kvc = [[KVC alloc] init];
```